# making subdomain in openshift same cartrigde

Tags: subdomain, openshift, openshift-cartridge

our application now needs subdomain for handling other parts of it, i was wondering how is it possible to make a single application with single application, as `subdomain.example.com` and `example.com` have same database, and we cannot keep two separate database. How to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I'm aware, you cannot have subdomains on OpenShift but you can have multiple OpenShift applications share the same database.
See this blog post: https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/

Comment: Another option would be to use one of the databases from the Marketplace at https://marketplace.openshift.com, you could easily access it from both of your applications.  But @MartinB is correct, you will probably need to run to separate applications instead of using two different aliases on the same application.